# How to timeout docker exec with complex command

Tags: docker, shell, timeout

I need to execute CFD(computational fluid dynamics) simulation on Docker container and orchestrate it with an external Python script. The computation may be arbitrarily long and has to be terminated after the timeout. Two issues making the problem complex is that;

1. There are multiple commands that should be connected with && and all of there stdout, stderr should be logged to a log file realtime(not after the completion).
2. One of the command is mpirun, which spawn multiple processes. All the child processes spawned by commands of 1. should be terminated recursively on timeout.

This is part of my attempt some what explains my intention.

```
inner_script = f"cartesianMesh && decomposePar && mpirun -np {c.num_proc} {foam_app} -parallel && reconstructPar"

f"""docker exec -w {c.container_case_dir_path} {docker_id} timeout {timeout_s}\
 bash -lc "{inner_script}" &> {c.container_log_file_path}) """
```

However it seems timeout does not work as expected and the `foam_app` keep runs in multiple processes.

How can I do it properly?

Comment: Can you implement the timeout at the Python layer, maybe using the [docker-py `Container.wait()` function](https://docker-py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/containers.html#docker.models.containers.Container.wait) to wait for the container to complete?  I'd avoid `docker exec` here, and I'd definitely avoid the `inner_script` setup where you try to embed one command in another.

Comment: @DavidMaze Thank you for the comment. I'll take a look at the docker-py. However, as I mentioned the computation could be ridiculously long, so can't just wait for the completion. Instead, one should terminate it on timeout.